# double value variable in windows command line

Tags: windows, cmd

i would like to write 10 random double values in a file using Windows command line. 
What is the best way to do it? Google gives no answer how to create a double variable in cmd.

Comment: Windows `cmd` arithmetic is limited to 32 bit signed integer numbers (-2,147,483,648 through 2,147,483,647) and  built-in variable called %RANDOM% an be used to generate random numbers in `0..32767` range. Use Powershell `Get-Random -Minimum $([double]::MinValue) -Maximum $([double]::MaxValue)`.

Comment: @JosefZ why not posting this as an answer? Sounds profound to me and deserves a more prominent place than a comment.